# I can't configure MacOS project to work with Firebase

Tags: firebase, macos

1. I have added the GoogleService-info-plist to the project.
2. I have checked and both the MacOs project and the Firebase's project have the same BundleID.
3. I also had donde several projects with iOS/SWiftUI and Firebase with no issues.
4. This is the first time I'm trying to connect Firebase to a MacOs project.
5. I have also deleted the GoogleService-info-plist file from the MacOs project, downloaded it again and added it via the XCode project/Add file process but I'm still getting this crash message...

2022-01-13 11:03:44.260253-0500 WebScraper[33494:19053189] 8.10.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2022-01-13 11:03:44.268425-0500 WebScraper[33494:19052756] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`FirebaseApp.configure()` could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist is added to the Xcode macOS target

Comment: GoogleService-Info.plist has been added to the Xcode macOS target. The error persist.